# how to add more outputs to neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

Of course no one making a neural network for image recognition and classification can make place for all possible image outputs. so If I make a neural network that takes the array input and get the output as a bird or not a bird. can I add more outputs for more images after I finish learning the first network or that will make the learning vanish.

so I add fixed input number and 1 output then I add 1 more and 1 more is that applicable or no?

Comment: so what is the solution ? how big companies create it ? do they create all image outputs types and possibilities before starting the neural network ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Retrain

If you can spend the resources, it would be a good thing to re-train (or to be more specific: train something from scratch) your network. But read the approaches following when you might achieve something better (or at least less costly).

## Transfer-learning

But if you are using one of the huge popular NNs which take weeks to train (on very costly) hardware, there might be a way touching the idea of *transfer-learning*.

There are at least two different approaches then:

#### Using the pretrained NN as feature-extractor

Here you will remove the final dense-layers and just use the trained NN to extract some features out of your images. Then you can build some arbitrarily new classifier on your new dataset, which maps OLD-NN-OUTPUT = FEATURES-INPUT -> classes (new softmax-NN or SVM/Kernel-SVM or anything else). This sounds quite robust if we assume that your pretrained NN is of high-quality and your new class is not too different from the learned ones.

In general this approach might be favorable if your new class + dataset is small and similar to the original one.

If the new data is not that similar, one might use some features at some earlier layer (more generic).

#### Continuing training

Here you would continue training the weights of your original NN, probably keeping the first layers (maybe even all but the final dense ones). As above the general idea is that we assume a good NN to be very general at the first layers (= extracting features) and more specific in the last ones.

This approach should be favorable if you got huge data for your new class. Depending on the similarity you might either continue to retrain all weights or if quite similar, fix some layer-weights (first ones).

There might be technical issues here how to achieve this approach (like different image-size inputs and other stuff). So it needs some work if some constraints of the original NN are broken. It's also important to tune the hyper-parameters for learning (maybe learning-rates should be lower!).

Comment: what do you mean by very general at the first layers and specefic at the end ? how i control it ? i know how to create inputs and hidden layers and outputs and it then takes and inputs and find pattern for output thats it .. how do i add more specefic features or parts at the end ?

Comment: That's a behaviour most Deep-convolutional NNs are showing and you are not controlling it. In general one should expect the NN to go from very general feature-extraction to more specific ones later with a final very specific classification-step due to dense-layers. That is nothing which is proved, but something which is our general understanding of these nets (emphasized by some papers which visualize what the inner layers are doing). And taking out some layers means modifying the code. So it well be different for different libs. It might not be an easy task for a beginner.

Comment: do i mean i make more than NNs one in the first and its output as input to the second NN and the output of second as input of third and so on .. ?

Comment: Try to be more formal with your descriptions. And take your time researching basic CNN-stuff and reading again the approaches above.

Comment: ok sorry for asking alot but one more question can i standarize the input image size i i take it 20x20 and its is 40x40 .. can i make it smaller so it fit the input ? and sorry for asking alot and thanks alot .. i will read more then come to your answer

Comment: If your new class-images are of different size, you can of course resize these to use the already trained NN. Depending on the two sizes, you might lose information (40 -> 20) or add noise due to interpolation (20 -> 40).